# Rails 3 search algorithm implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm

I am writing a filtering algorithm that takes the user input as array, like

```
@keywords = [['undergrad','grad'],['SAT', 'GPA'], ['Stanford']]
```

and to query the table, for example, videos table in my database. There's a string field in the table which includes a couple of tags delimited by comma.

The logic is:

```
In all videos, if the tags include "undergrad", "grad", returned those videos;
In the returned videos, if the tags include "SAT", "GPA", returned those videos;
In the returned videos, if the tags include "Stanford", returned those videos;
```

Any help on implementing it on Rails?

Comment: How are you implementing tagging? Are you using something like https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on or are they just fields in your video table?

Comment: So the tags is a field includes words delimited by comma, e.x, "undergrad,GPA"

Comment: stored directly in your video model?

Comment: yes, in the video model(table)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgres you can do something like this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html in your where statement.

Or MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html